# ResultSet giving me the first row only

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm trying to read string values from my database to insert them in an arraylist of strings. However, my loop stops after completing only one row.

That's my code,

```
 public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        Statement stmt = null;
        String query = "SELECT CustomerName FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CustomerName IS NOT NULL";
        try {
            Connection conn1 = DBConnection.getConnection();
            stmt = conn1.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            // iterate through the java resultset
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("CustomerName"));
                customersnames.add(rs.getString("CustomerName"));

            }
            stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception at initialize ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(customer, customersnames);
        } catch (NullPointerException E) {

        }

    }
```

and that's what I'm getting

null (that's in red)
heee
Exception at initialize

"heee" is the first row of my database, but I have many more, that's what it's reading only and it's throwing an exception.

Comment: Please point out the exact line where the problem is in your code?  Nothing looks obviously wrong to me.

Comment: The thing is, nothing is wrong with the code, but my database contains many rows and the code is reading only the first row, the problem must be somewhere in the while loop.

Comment: But what happens ? Is there some exception or it just leave the while loop ?

Comment: Where is `customersnames` defined? Does it refer to a valid object? What exception is being thrown?  If you didn't initialize or assign `customersnames`, `customersnames.add(...)` will die with `NullPointerException`.

Comment: It's probably because he didn't initialize the 'customernames' list, but it is hard to say because it's a part of code

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you get a NullPointerException after having printed the result of the first row.
Did you initialize your object `customersnames`?

In order to be sure, change `System.err.println(e.getMessage());` into `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: I forgot to initialize it . You made my day ! Thank you.